# Get the next value from SequenceGenerator

Tags: jpa, sequence-generators

I'd like to make use of SequenceGenerator and get the next value from the sequence generator. I want to avoid making a trip to the DB and rely on the sequencegenerator to give me a unique value. Also I am using the value to display the unique id in a display field without persisting the object.

Answer (score 5):

It works in Oracle:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT nombreSecuencia.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");

return (java.math.BigDecimal)q.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

To get only next sequence value you can use the following:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select nextval('schema.sequence_name')");
return (Long)q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I've added an Oracle variant that I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

If we overlook [JPA value generation strategies](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated), [SEQUENCE strategy](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Sequence_Strategy_) is the best in your case.

> Unlike AUTO and IDENTITY, the SEQUENCE strategy generates an automatic
> value as soon as a new entity object is persisted (i.e. **before
> commit**). This may be useful when the primary key value is needed
> earlier. To **minimize round trips** to the database server, IDs are
> allocated in groups.
>
> The number of IDs in each allocation is specified by the allocationSize attribute.

If you need generated ID from the sequence earlier, just persist the object and retrieve its ID. Later you can remove it from persistence context.

---

I am not sure why do you need ID before you persist. And I think there is no point in getting value from sequence generator. I do not recommend you messing with generated values and I do not recommend you using manual values for ids. Use out-of-box functionality.